# Downloading issue from Copernicus Land Monitoring Services

Tags: download, copernicus

I cannot download any Geodatabase from Copernicus Land Monitoring Services. I need data for CORINE maps. I have registered and logged in but cannot download.

Comment: What's the actual question?  What have you tried? do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this link ? http://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc-2012 You can chose either the Corine Land cover vector or raster.

[image: CLC2012_Map]

[image: CLC_2012_download]

Comment: OH, yes, i just checked, you need to register. I'll have a try up to the end.

Comment: A window shows up that says downloading will start soon but then suddenly I am back to the previous page.

Comment: Did you try logging in first ?  For info, i'm using Chrome and it works.

Comment: Yes, I did log in

Comment: What internet browser do you use ?

Comment: Google Chrome. I turned off uBlock Origin (adblock) but still...

Comment: I got it to work with Internet Explorer (!). For some reason new tabs are being blocked in Chrome. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: No problem, it's a pleasure to help. Don't forget to click on the V next to my answer to indicate it solved your problem (for other users)

Answer (score 1):

You can download CORINE data from the EEA website

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-3

Comment: Thank you! But seperate file for every land use code!?